# How to enable promoted results in modern pnp search app search result

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react

How to enable promoted results in modern pnp search app search results?

MS Search showing the promoted results are first.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these by enabling query rules in the PnP web parts.

The Microsoft Search box do not show promoted results, the search result page does - and, that capability is being replaced by the new Bookmarks feature over time. You can however still use query rules and promoted results with the SharePoint API provider in the PnP web parts.

> https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/blob/develop/docs/search-parts/templating.md#accessing-items

> https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/issues/614